# Making a new column that is a ratio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
mob.columns
Out[806]: Index([u'country', u'maxterm', u'quantity'], dtype='object')
```

Here is some data:

```
mob.head(5) 
Out[807]: 
      country maxterm  quantity
0      China    aled        44
1      China    fanx        77
2      China    grrx        12
3      China    hldo        13
4      China    jnmp        29
```

What is the simplest way to create a new column that is a ratio of the quantity listed on each row to the sum of all the quantities for each country?   I was trying groupby and pivot and making a lambda function.  This attempt

```
mob.groupby(['country', 'maxterm'])['quantity'].apply(lambda x: x / float(sum(x)) )
```

didn't work, it just outputted a bunch of 1's.  It would be best if I can just make a new column in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transform`

```
mob.quantity / mob.groupby('country').quantity.transform('sum')

0    0.251429
1    0.440000
2    0.068571
3    0.074286
4    0.165714
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```

---

Create a new column with `assign`

```
mob.assign(ratio=mob.groupby('country').quantity.transform(lambda x: x / x.sum()))

  country maxterm  quantity     ratio
0   China    aled        44  0.251429
1   China    fanx        77  0.440000
2   China    grrx        12  0.068571
3   China    hldo        13  0.074286
4   China    jnmp        29  0.165714
```

---

**Choice of Calculation**

```
%timeit mob.quantity.values / mob.groupby('country').quantity.transform('sum').values
%timeit mob.groupby('country').quantity.transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
%timeit mob.quantity / mob.groupby('country').quantity.transform('sum')

1000 loops, best of 3: 956 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
```

Comment: I was really struggling not knowing assign :)